# Attribute Table not showing newly created features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, editing, file-geodatabase

I'm using ArcMap. I have a File Geodatabase Feature Class stored in a network geodatabase. I have approximately 30 feature classes on our "Master" mxd file, but one of them has a major issue. When I use editor to create a new feature in this class, the new feature is shown on the map. However, the new feature is not shown in the attribute table. I've tried sorting by ascending and descending on the ObjectID, and it is nowhere to be found. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? License level and if you are adding the feature through any third party extension?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.6. We have the basic license. One of our assistants is in charge of digitizing this layer. She noticed the problem and I had the same issue. It appears that when I save the edits, close ArcMap, and reopen, the new features appear in the attribute table. It's too soon to tell if that is a fluke or a solution.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a spatial index issue, things can "disappear" but are really there. Consider backing up the database then compacting the one you are editing, also recalculating feature extent can solve issues.

Comment: It could also be a lock, if you have two people looking at the same database the new rows could be locked until the database lock is released when you exit ArcMap. As the feature is visible on the map but doesn't show in the table it could be the cache, especially because the table is over a network, there's a button on the top left of the attribute table 'reload cache', try that and see if the rows appear. I don't recommend editing over a network unless you are using an enterprise database, too much scope for corruption; I hope you're backing up your data daily.

Comment: I think this is it. I'm the GIS Specialist, and other than me, only the Administrative Assistant has access to edit layers. She has one layer that she is in charge of. Both times that we faced this issue, it was when I was putting in as-built plans and she was editing her layer. We have an IT company that backs up our data every night. Thank you for the comment, I think this is the answer.

Comment: I would check definition queries as well.  you can draw and see the sketch sometimes, but if it doesn't match the definition query it wont show up in the attribute table.  mxd's can also get corrupted. Try adding the layer to a new blank map and see if that helps too.  Its been a bit of a usual practice around here to recreate mxds every few years/months so they don't get too bloated.  Especially Master map versions.